# Edit JSON object

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I converted a excel file to a JSON object in R using jsonlite package.I want the whole array as a value to a key and add other some more key value pairs to that object.

The JSON array I got after converting the excel file looks like this -

```
[{
        "Sno": xxx,
        "Token": xxx,
        "Name": "xxx",
        "Location": "xxxx",
        "COE": "xxx",
        "Grade": "xxx",

    }, {
        "Sno": xxx,
        "Token": xxx,
        "Name": "xxxx",
        "Location": "xxxx",
        "COE": "xxxx",
        "Grade": "xxx",
    }, {
```

and so on..

The output i require is -:

```
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": [{
            "Sno": xxx,
            "Token": xxx,
            "Name": "xxx",
            "Location": "xxxx",
            "COE": "xxx",
            "Grade": "xxx",

        }, {
            "Sno": xxx,
            "Token": xxx,
            "Name": "xxxx",
            "Location": "xxxx",
            "COE": "xxxx",
            "Grade": "xxx",
        }, {
```

Please suggest how to do it or atleast point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out like this-

```
x<-list(key1="value1",key2="value2",key3="value3",key4=list(data_frame))
library(jsonlite)
final<-toJSON(x)
```